# SSRS report Query. The replace function requires 3 argument(s). Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2012

I found a script for splitting values from a multi-valued parameter. It works perfectly when I run it on SQL Server, but gives me an error when trying to run it on the SSRS report dataset. Here's the code below.

```
DECLARE @tblStart TABLE (ID int IDENTITY (1, 1), StartDates varchar(max)) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@MonthStart,',', ''' UNION SELECT ''') + 
'''' ;

INSERT INTO @tblStart (StartDates)
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Please assist

[image]

Comment: Try to `print` your `@SQL` variable before executing it. Than you can find the error more easily.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try

Comment: I get the same error when trying to run it on the Query Designer, but looks fine when running it on SQL Server

Comment: Can you post the value of @SQL when you try to execute it?

Comment: SELECT '2017-03-26' UNION SELECT '2017-04-30' UNION SELECT 
 '2017-05-28' UNION SELECT '2017-06-25' UNION SELECT '2017-07-30' UNION SELECT '2017-08-27' UNION SELECT '2017-09-24' UNION SELECT '2017-10-29' UNION SELECT '2017-11-26' UNION SELECT '2017-12-24' UNION SELECT '2018-01-28' UNION SELECT '2018-02-24'

Comment: The error doesn't look to be anything to do with the dynamic SQL as that shouldn't contain `REPLACE`. How are you trying to use this in SSRS? Can  you add a screenshot?

Comment: I've just added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the parameter in the dataset to join the values together E.G.

```
JOIN(parThirdParties,",")
```